# While creating a new cluster of EMR on AWS, getting this error `EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole is invalid`

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to create a new EMR cluster of Apache-Spark for the first time from my account and getting this error

`Terminated with errorsFailed to provision ec2 instances because 'The requested instance profile EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole is invalid'`

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling autoscaling when creating the EMR cluster.

If your cluster uses autoscaling, it needs a role for the autoscaling. Depending on the way you create the cluster, that particular role might be created automatically for you.

You can read more on the topic [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-automatic-scaling.html).